# How do I generate questions (such as multiple choice or true/false) about a text using Spacy?

Tags: nlp, spacy

I have large text documents that talk about something, and I need to automatically generate multiple choice or true/false questions about what is discussed in these documents.

Are there any libraries/frameworks I could use with Spacy to import these documents and generate such questions? For example, if the document has a sentence saying "There were only two at her house." a possible question could be "True or false: there were only three at her house?".

I looked through Spacy documentation but could not find anything relevant...

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: added a clarification